# Obfuscation + Wrapper, will that work?

Tags: c#, obfuscation, wrapper

I want to place in my program run-time wrapper (**Microsoft.CSharp**, **cssscript** or so). I also want to obfuscate my code with **Eazfuscator.NET**. Will this work?

Eg, there's an Object **Lol** of class **Lool2** in my program.
Will it be possible to use that object in my program's wrapper like
Lol.doanything() after obfuscating whole solution?

I'm having doubts and thats why I'm asking here. I couldnt find the answer on the net though

Comment: Not very clear what you want to call where/how.

Comment: I simply want to put some kind of a run-time scripter in my program. Then I want to obfuscate whole solution and I'm wondering if scripter is going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Eazfuscator.NET but this information goes for most obfuscators.

Most obfuscators by default rename **non-public** types and members to conceal their meaning. Public types are not renamed. They also usually have an **internalize** feature that first changes all `public`s to `internal`s (so then they are included in the rename feature).

They also allow you to disable renaming as a whole or for specific types (using the `System.Reflection.ObfuscationAttribute`), even when they are not public. This is required when you're accessing non-public members using reflection.

If you're not using reflection, an alternative is to merge (also a feature quite alot of obfuscators have) the application with the wrapper and internalize everything. That way all types can be renamed.

Comment: It allows you to access assembly information, create objects and call methods at runtime. You could, for instance, let your code invoke a random method. It comes with a big performance penalty though. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55710/Reflection-in-NET for more information.